# Python ImportError: No module named requests

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

Hey im trying to executing a script but he prints :

```
ImportError: No module named requests
```

So I installed this module with the command :

```
pip install requests
```

This installed it, to make sure I checked with a `pip list` and requests (2.11.0) is appearing

So I thought everything would be good now but after i execute my python script again the same error appearing:

```
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Comment: is pip running in the same environment as python?
Check with pip -V and python -V.

Comment: When I execute pip -V I get Python3.5 and when I execute python -V I get Python 2.7.8

Comment: [Change your PATH variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) (Refer to section 3.3.1) so that you are using both from the same environment, whether that is Python2 or Python3.

Comment: In the path, whichever python version scripts folder of python installation comes first, that will take the priority. Make sure you are using same pip (2.x) and same python(2.x)